# In Ruby on Rails rake task is calling a function from another rake file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, function, rake, dry, code-duplication

As you can see, I've defined a function inside a rake file. No problem, that works fine. Problem is, when I declare `def get_user_input` in **another rake file**. In that case the **function gets called from another .rake file** Can you suggest anything? Thanks.

```
namespace :backtest do

  def get_user_input
    if ENV['date_from'].present? && ENV['date_until'].present? 
      # get input...
    else
      abort 'Sample usage: blah blah...'
    end
  end

  desc "Start backtest"
  task :start => :environment do
    get_user_input
    # rest of the code...
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Moved the functions into a module and the problem gone.

```
namespace :backtest do

 Module MY
  def self.get_user_input
    if ENV['date_from'].present? && ENV['date_until'].present? 
      # get input...
    else
      abort 'Sample usage: blah blah...'
    end
  end
 end

 desc "Start backtest"
 task :start => :environment do
   My.get_user_input
   # rest of the code...
 end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
require 'rake'
load 'your_rake_file_name_here.rake'
get_user_input
```